# allocating elements - arrays in Mips assembly language

Tags: memory, assembly, multidimensional-array, mips, allocation

I have a two dimensional array which looks like
A: .byte 'A','B','C','D'
   .byte 'E','F','G','H'

but I would like to make each element fit two characters
e.g
.byte "8C","9A" ...etc

how to allocate 2 byte for each element to make it hold two characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.ascii "8C9A"
```

The size of elements only makes sense in your code, it's not necessary to define that in the data.